# Using custom object as dictionary key but get values by object property

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, collections

I have a class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

And I need to create a dictionary where key is object of Foo. Like this:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo { Name = "Foo1", Value = 2.2 };
Foo foo2 = new Foo { Name = "Foo2", Value = 3.6 };

Dictionary<Foo, int> dic = new Dictionary<Foo, int>();
dic.Add(foo1, 1234);
dic.Add(foo2, 2345);
```

And now I want to get values from dictionary by passing Foo.Name property as key. Like this:

```
int i=dic["Foo1"];
// i==1234
i = dic["Foo2"];
// i==2345
```

Is it possible? Or the only way to pass object of Foo as key and override Equals method?

Comment: Do you ever *need* to look up a value with `Foo` as the key? Could you just use a `Dictionary<string, int>` instead?

Comment: That won't work. The issue being you used an instance of class type Foo as keys. You have to use the same instance as key again to fetch the value. register the foo1.ToString() as key and not the instance so you can fetch it like dic["Foo1"]; FYI this is a dictionary<string,int>

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `Foo` as a key, you will need to use a `Foo` to index the dictionary as well.

Provided that what you actually need is most likely a `Dictionary<string, int>`, you could try overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` so that you can compare `Foo` objects based on the name only:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Foo {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        Foo other = obj as Foo;
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Foo foo1 = new Foo { Name = "Foo1", Value = 2.2 };
        Foo foo2 = new Foo { Name = "Foo2", Value = 3.6 };

        Dictionary<Foo, int> dic = new Dictionary<Foo, int>();
        dic.Add(foo1, 1234);
        dic.Add(foo2, 2345);

        int i = dic[new Foo { Name = "Foo1" }];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class Program
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo { Name = "Foo1", Value = 2.2 };
        Foo foo2 = new Foo { Name = "Foo2", Value = 3.6 };

        var dic = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Foo, int>>();
        dic.Add(foo1.Name, new KeyValuePair<Foo, int>(foo1, 1234));
        dic.Add(foo2.Name, new KeyValuePair<Foo, int>(foo2, 2345));

        int x = dic["Foo1"].Value;

        var y = dic["Foo2"].Value;

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(y);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Result will be:

1234

2345

Answer (score -1):

The `Dictionary` is based on a hash table, that means it uses a hash lookup, which is a rather efficient algorithm to look up things. I suggest you think on your design and just use `Dictionary<string,int>`if you just want to use `string` as `key`

As a work around( not preferred way use only if you can't change your design), you could do this.

```
var key = dic.Keys.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Name == "Foo1");     

if(key != null)
    dic[key]; //
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I solved it by creating a class inherits Dictionary and overriding get value method. This solves my problem but I'm not sure about productivity with large collections.

```
public class MyDictionary:Dictionary<Foo, int>
{
    public Bar():base()
    {

    }

    new public int this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this[base.Keys.Single(a => a.Name == key)];
        }
    }
}
```

And then this code works well:

```
    MyDictionary<Foo, int> dic = new MyDictionary<Foo, int>();
    dic.Add(foo1, 1234);
    dic.Add(foo2, 2345);
    int i=dic["Foo1"];
```